# How do I make things I type save into a var and make the print command type that var as an output

Tags: python

I have tried but I cant do it. tried searching through this website and still couldn't, sorry to waste your time in easy stuff here is my bad code and I hope you put your good code under here
`var1 = input() print(&var1&)`
please help me a lot and good luck on anything that comes hard to you about this and I'm sorry to bother u I am just making this extremely long so that it will make my question easy to post you don't have to do anything of this

Comment: More apology than code. Please invert it!

Comment: `var1 = input() print(var1)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you intend to print the user input, just remove the `&` from either side of your variable.

```py
>>> var1 = input()
spam  # Type your input.
>>> print(var1)
spam
```